# External output to vim buffer AFTER command completes

Tags: shell, vim, racket

*I'm currently using gVim on Windows 7*

Running a command like:

```
:r! racket %
```

I am able to successfully read in the desired output about half of the time. The rest of the time, nothing is read. It seems to be an issue with vim reading in the output before the shell execution has terminated and actually generated some output.

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens if you leave off the the trailing '%' (and why do you need that?)? good luck.

Comment: The `%` is essential. It runs the command on the current file.

Comment: Is the failure dependent on the code that you're running the vim command across, or is it entirely random? If you run a command other than `racket`, does it still fail half the time?. Are there any error codes? What happens when you run `racket` on the code outside of vim?

Comment: @BartonChittenden any racket code will fail to be read half the time. The same commands on the command line will always succeed. PHP and Python code will always be read in. There are no error codes. Seems like some trouble between racket and vim specifically . . .

Answer (score 0):

From `:help :r!`

```
:[range]r[ead] !{cmd}   Execute {cmd} and insert its standard output below
            the cursor or the specified line.  A temporary file is
            used to store the output of the command which is then
            read into the buffer.  'shellredir' is used to save
            the output of the command, which can be set to include
            stderr or not.  {cmd} is executed like with ":!{cmd}",
            any '!' is replaced with the previous command |:!|.
```

It could be that you need to set `:help shellredir` to include stderr.